# I want to return the response from here in j2me

Tags: java, lwuit, j2mepolish

I want to return the response from here using a progress pane so that i can show a Loading dialog. The code is working fine but sometimes i am not able to get the response from here.

The Code Snippet is:

```
public class Connection
{

  StringBuffer messageBuffer = new StringBuffer();
  String response;

  public String connect(String str, String type)
  {
    try 
    {
        ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest()
        {
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input)
            {
                try
                {
                    // just read from the response input stream
                    System.out.println("input length: "+input.available());
                    //byte[] b = new byte[input.available()];
                    //input.read(b, 0, input.available());
                    byte[] b ;
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bStrm = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    int ch;
                    while ((ch = input.read()) != -1)
                        bStrm.write(ch);
                    b = bStrm.toByteArray();
                    System.err.println(b.length);                        
                    response = new String(b);                        
                    System.err.println(new String(b));
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {                        
                    System.err.println("IOException :"+ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
            protected void postResponse()
            {                    
            }
        };
        cr.setTimeout(3600);
        cr.setUrl(str.trim());     
        Progress progress = new Progress("Loading...", cr,true);
        progress.setAutoShow(true);
        progress.setDisposeOnCompletion(true);

        if (type.equals("POST"))
        {
            cr.setPost(true);
        } else
        {
            cr.setPost(false);
        }
        NetworkManager nm = NetworkManager.getInstance();
        nm.setTimeout(60000);
        nm.start();
        nm.addToQueueAndWait(cr);
        return response;
    }        
    catch (Exception ae)
    {
        System.out.println(ae.getMessage());
        return response;
    }
    finally
    {
        return response;
    }

  }

}



public class Progress extends Dialog implements ActionListener
{
    private ConnectionRequest request;
    private boolean disposeOnCompletion;
    private boolean autoShow;

    public Progress(String title, ConnectionRequest request) {
        this(title, request, false);
    }

    public Progress(String title, ConnectionRequest request, boolean showPercentage) {
        super(title);
        try {
            this.request = request;
            SliderBridge b = new SliderBridge(request);
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            addComponent(b);
            setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(false);
            setAutoDispose(false);
            NetworkManager.getInstance().addProgressListener(this);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void actionCommand(Command cmd) {
        if(Display.getInstance().isTouchScreenDevice() || getSoftButtonCount() < 2) {
            for(int iter = 0 ; iter < getComponentCount() ; iter++) {
                Component c = getComponentAt(iter);
                if(c instanceof Button) {
                    c.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        } else {
            removeAllCommands();
        }
        request.kill();
    }
    public boolean isDisposeOnCompletion() {
        return disposeOnCompletion;
    }
    public void setDisposeOnCompletion(boolean disposeOnCompletion) {
        this.disposeOnCompletion = disposeOnCompletion;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        NetworkEvent ev = (NetworkEvent)evt;
        if(ev.getConnectionRequest() == request) {
            if(disposeOnCompletion && ev.getProgressType() == NetworkEvent.PROGRESS_TYPE_COMPLETED) {
                dispose();
                return;
            }
            if(autoShow && Display.getInstance().getCurrent() != this) {
                show();
            }
        }
    }
    public boolean isAutoShow() {
        return autoShow;
    }

    public void setAutoShow(boolean autoShow) {
        this.autoShow = autoShow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should use the `setProgress(value)` method in somewhere of your code. And you must do it using a `Thread`.

Take a look here [LWUIT Progress bar](http://lwuit.blogspot.com.es/2008/05/progress-indicator-threads-in-lwuit.html)

In that blog they explain how to set the value to the progress bar, using threads.

Comment: Sorry @jmunoz your ans didn't helped. I just want to return response from here but what is happening is that sometimes it returns from here and sometimes even after getting he response it is not able to return. I can give u a look of my Progress class also. I have edited my question.